# Virtual Memory - Calculating the Virtual Address Space

Tags: virtual-memory

I am studying for an exam tomorrow and I came across this question:

```
You are given a memory system with 2MB of virtual memory, 8KB page size,
512 MB of physical memory, TLB contains 16 entries, 2-way set associative.

How many bits are needed to represent the virtual address space?
```

I was thinking it would be 20 bits, since 2^10 is 1024, so I simply multiply 2^10*2^10 and get 2^20. However, the answer ends up being 21 and I have no idea why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The virtual address space required is 2MB.

As you have calculated, 20 bits can accomodate 1MB of VM space. You need 21 bits to accomodate 2MB.